# Why might pfsense be removing the link-local ipv6 address for my wan interface?

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, pfsense

I am a Comcast customer, using IPv6 through a pfSense hardware appliance (PCEngines APU, running version 2.4.3-RELEASE.)

I have setup my IPv6 on pfSense to ask for prefix delegations, which occasionally works and will continue to work up until a day or two later where it then stops working.  This leads me to believe that my link-local address might have a timer expiration that causes it to be aged out of the system.  When I login to the pfSense firewall via ssh, that thought is confirmed: no link-local address on re0 (my WAN interface.)

When dhcp6c tries to renew the IA-NA and IA-PD data from Comcast, I get a "cannot assign requested address" in the logs, which I assume is because dhcp6c is trying to use a link-local address to which is not assigned on the interface.

While I'm aware that FreeBSD has a few things one can try to fix the issue, I'm less aware of how pfSense would prefer that I go fiddling with settings relating to this.  I'm hoping that someone might have some feedback on this issue that might point me in a direction to solve it.

Comment: You should report it as a bug. I couldn't find this in any of the pfsense issue trackers for this release. https://forum.netgate.com

Comment: I agree, bug report first. This behavior is most likely broken.